# jQuery - outputting updated HTML after using replaceWith

Tags: jquery, dom, replacewith

The live example (which only works in FireFox. Still working on that):
http://taylorcammack.com/projects/twitter-story/

A little intro: jQuery novice so the syntax may be rough, trying to create a container for a standard Twitter widget.

Here's the function that is used to update the head & subhead. I'm using a similar method to update the widget ID which I haven't added.

```
    $('.submit').click(function(){
    $('.header_twitter').replaceWith("<div class=\"header_twitter\">#" + searchTerm + "</div>");
    $('.subhead_twitter').replaceWith("<div class=\"subhead_twitter\">" + twitSubhead + "</div>" );
});
```

After updating the head & subhead, I scrape the #embedContainer div via:

```
var embedCode = $( "#embedContainer" ).html();
$('.generateEmbed').click(function(){
    $('.embed').text("" + embedCode + "");
});
```

The issue I'm having is that the embed container is not registering the HTML that was updated with the replaceWith. Any ideas?

Comment: well of course it isn't.. you're only getting the html once, before the click happens. after that you're just  outputting the same html on each click, never going back to the dom to get new html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define embedcode within the click event function

```
$('.generateEmbed').click(function(){
    var embedCode = $( "#embedContainer" ).html();
    $('.embed').text("" + embedCode + "");
});
```